# Select the first sibling of each different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```js
$('.editbtn3').click(function() {
  var edit = $(this).text().trim() == 'Edit';
  $(this).html($(this).text().trim() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
  var $rows = $("tr.set" + $(this).data("set"));

  $rows.each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
if(index==0)
{

  var tdSet = $(this).find($("td").not('td:first-child').not('td:nth-child(2)').not('td:nth-child(3)').not(':last-child'));
}
else

  var tdSet=$(this).find($("td"));




    tdSet.each(function() {
      if (edit) {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true).css({
          'background': '#fff',
          'color': '#000'
        })
      } else {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false).removeAttr("style");
      }

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table0 table2 table-striped table-dark table-bordered" id="myTable">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th scope="col" rowspan="2">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col" rowspan="2">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col" rowspan="2">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col" colspan="5">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col" colspan="5">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col" rowspan="2">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col" rowspan="2">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col" rowspan="2">S.N</th>
     
               </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                    <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                    <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                    <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                    <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                    <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                    <th scope="col">S.N</th>
                  <th scope="col">S.N</th>
               </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr class="set0">
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>20</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td >21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21
                  </td>
                  <td>  <button type="button" data-set="0" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">
                     Edit
                     </button>
                   
                  </td>
               </tr>
               
               <tr class="set1">
                  <td rowspan="2">1</td>
                  <td rowspan="2">20</td>
                  <td rowspan="2">21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td >21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="2">21st August</td>
                  <td  rowspan="2">21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="2">21st August</td>
                  <td  rowspan="2">21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="2">21st August</td>
                  <td rowspan="2">21</td>
                  <td rowspan="2">21
                  </td>
                  <td rowspan="2" >  <button type="button" data-set="1" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">
                     Edit
                     </button>
                   
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="set1">

                
                                       <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>

                 
               </tr>
           
             
               
                        <tr class="set2">
                  <td rowspan="3">2</td>
                  <td rowspan="3">20</td>
                  <td rowspan="3">21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td >21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="3">21st August</td>
                  <td  rowspan="3">21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="3">21st August</td>
                  <td  rowspan="3">21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="3">21st August</td>
                  <td rowspan="3">21</td>
                  <td rowspan="3">21
                  </td>
                  <td rowspan="3" >  <button type="button" data-set="2" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">
                     Edit
                     </button>
                   
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="set2">
               
                
                                       <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>

                 
               </tr>
               <tr class="set2">
                  
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                 
               
                 
                
               </tr>
               <!--     <tr class="set2">
                  
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                 
               
                 
                
               </tr> -->
               
                        <tr class="set3">
                  <td rowspan="4">3</td>
                  <td rowspan="4">20</td>
                  <td rowspan="4">21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td >21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="4">21st August</td>
                  <td  rowspan="4">21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="4">21st August</td>
                  <td  rowspan="4">21</td>
                  <td  rowspan="4">21st August</td>
                  <td rowspan="4">21</td>
                  <td rowspan="4">21
                  </td>
                  <td rowspan="4" >  <button type="button" data-set="3" class="btn btn-primary editbtn3">
                     Edit
                     </button>
                   
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr class="set3">
               
                
                                       <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>

                 
               </tr>
               <tr class="set3">
                  
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                 
               
                 
                
               </tr>
                   <tr class="set3">
                  
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                  <td>21</td>
                  <td>21st August</td>
                 
               
                 
                
               </tr>
               
               
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
```

What I am trying to acheive here is that when we click on edit button,the first, second and 3rd column data and the last field data should be uneditable but what is happenning here is that for the first row,The desired fields are editable but on clicking the edit button of 2nd row and 3rd row everything else is editable.I was trying to select the first sibling of tr having different classes and making their first,second,third and last field data uneditable. May be the problem is due to the wrong selection. Is there any way to do it without the use of class? 
Here is my code snippet

Comment: You can try: eq() Selector of Jquery, `$(this).closest("tr").eq(0)`

Comment: Sorry,when I added eq(),every row became uneditable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check **DOM** selection with var `tdSet` for odd and even rows.

use below code snippet.

```js
$('.edit').click(function() {
  var edit = $(this).text().trim() == 'Edit';
  $(this).html($(this).text().trim() == 'Edit' ? 'Save' : 'Edit');
  var $rows = $("tr.set" + $(this).data("set"));
  $rows.each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var tdSet = $(this).find($("td")).not(':first').not('td:eq(0)').not(':last');
    if (index % 2) {
      tdSet = $(this).find($("td")).not('td:eq(0)');
    }

    tdSet.each(function() {
      if (edit) {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', true).css({
          'background': '#fff',
          'color': '#000'
        })
      } else {
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false).removeAttr("style");
      }
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table0  table-striped table-dark table-bordered" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">abc</th>
      <th scope="col">cde</th>
      <th scope="col">fgh</th>
      <th scope="col">fgh</th>
      <th scope="col">fgh</th>
      <th scope="col">fgh</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="set1">
      <td rowspan="2">abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td rowspan="2">abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td rowspan="2"> 
        <button type="button" data-set="1" class="btn btn-primary edit">
          Edit
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set1">
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set2">
      <td rowspan="2">abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td rowspan="2">abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <button type="button" data-set="2" class="btn btn-primary edit">
          Edit
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="set2">
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you are mistaken.I don't want to edit only second row.Let me make you clear,I want to edit every element of row except first,second and last column by clicking the button of that row.

Comment: @samanaghimire updated logic accordingly. have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but I'm having problems.The code above works perfectly fine for 2 rows  but in my case there maybe two,three or four rows and i don't know how to handle  all rows having different rowspan.I will update the code your your review.Thankyou